# Is an elliptic curve that is isomorphic to its Frobenius conjugate defined over $\mathbb{F}_p$?

Tags: elliptic-curves, galois-descent

Let $p$ be prime and $q = p^n$. Let $E$ be an elliptic curve over $\mathbb{F}_q$, and let $E^{(p)}$ be the pullback of $E$ by the $p$-power Frobenius of $\mathbb{F}_q$. If $E$ is isomorphic (over $\mathbb{F}_q$) to its Galois conjugate $E^{(p)}$, then does it follow that $E$ is the base change of an elliptic curve over $\mathbb{F}_p$? If so, what is the argument?

Note that similar statements are not true over infinite fields: for instance, $\mathbb{Q}$-curves are isomorphic to all their Galois conjugates, yet need not descend to actual elliptic curves over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: $\mathbb{Q}$-curves are **isogenous** to all their Galois conjugates, not necessarily isomorphic.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Almost, but not quite. If $j(E)$ is the $j$-invariant of $E$ then, under your hypothesis, $j(E)=j(E^{(p)})=j(E)^p$, so $j(E) \in \mathbb{F}_p$. Hence $E$ is either defined over $\mathbb{F}_p$ or is a twist of such a curve. If you take the quadratic twist in $\mathbb{F}_{p^2}$ of an elliptic curve defined over $\mathbb{F}_p$ you get a counterexample.

Comment: The quadratic twist in $\mathbb{F}_{p^2}$ of an elliptic curve defined over $\mathbb{F}_p$ is still an elliptic curve defined over $\mathbb{F}_p$, so I don't see how this is a counterexample. I agree with the rest of what you say but don't see how it settles my question.

Comment: If the curve over the prime field is $y^2=f(x)$ take $d \in \mathbb{F}_{p^2}$, not a square in that field and consider $dy^2=f(x)$. That's not the same as twisting over the prime field (this would isomorphic to the first curve over the quadratic equation).

Comment: Why is this curve isomorphic to its $p$-Frobenius pullback and why doesn't it descend to $\mathbb{F}_p$ (maybe after changing the Weierstrass equation one could get rid of $d$)?

Comment: The Frobenius is $d^py^2=f(x)$ but you can write $d^py^2 = d(d^{(p-1)/2}y)^2$, so the two curves are isomorphic. If it descended to the prime field it would be isomorphic to $y^2=f(x)$ or $cy^2=f(x)$, with $c$ in the prime field but these two curves are isomorphic to each other over the quadratic extension and, since $d$ is not a square, $dy^2=f(x)$ is not isomorphic to $y^2=f(x)$.

Comment: Sorry, I am allergic to Weierstrass equations. But thank you--I think I understand that this works (away from $j = 0, 1728$ at least): for $E_0/\mathbb{F}_p$ with $Aut_{\overline{\mathbb{F}}_p} = \{ \pm 1\}$, there's only one other ell. curve $/\mathbb{F}_p$ in the geometric isomorphism class of $E_0$, and it becomes isomorphic to $E_0$ over $\mathbb{F}_{p^2}$; similarly, $E$ you construct isn't isomorphic to $(E_0)_{\mathbb{F}_{p^2}}$, so can't descend to $\mathbb{F}_p$, and is isomorphic to $E^{(p)}$ b/c formation of quad. twist commutes with any field auto. due to unique the quad. extn.

Comment: @LisaS.: Let $E_0$ be an elliptic curve over $k_0$ (size $q_0$), and $k/k_0$ finite. For an elliptic curve $E$ over $k$ satisfying $E\simeq E^{(q_0)}$, does $E$ arise from a $k_0$-form of $E_0$; i.e., for $A={\rm{Aut}}_{E_0/k_0}$ the finite etale Aut-scheme, is the image of $f:H^1(k_0,A)\rightarrow H^1(k,A_k)$ characterized by invariance under composing $q_0$-Frobenius $A_k \rightarrow A_k^{(q_0)}$ (isom.!) with scalar extension of the canonical $A^{(q_0)} \simeq A$? This composite is identity if $A=\mu_n$ (constant dual!), so fails when $n|\#k^{\times}$ with $k\supset k_0^{1/n}$.

Comment: @LisaS.: The same holds for $A = \mathbf{Z}/(2)$ for any $p$ with $[k:k_0]$ is even. But the cases $A = \mu_n$ for some $n$ not divisible by $p$ and $A = \mathbf{Z}/(2)$ for any $p$ cover all cases except for $p=2, 3$ with $j=0=1728$. Hence, we have uniformly handled all cases except supersingular elliptic curves in characteristics 2 and 3.

Comment: @grghxy: Thank you. This is the kind of argument I was hoping for. A friend showed me a similar argument that I couldn't understand, and even gave me a reference: Deligne, Rapoport "Les schemas de modules de courbes elliptiques", page 133 (starts with "autrement dit") of how to descend to $\mathbb{F}_p$ in a similar situation. The reference was really mysterious to me, but I thought that if that argument really works, then my question should also have a positive answer. Do you have any comments on what is going on in the reference I've mentioned?

Comment: @LisaS.: Perhaps ask your friend to explain their argument or D-R more clearly?  Anyway, the D-R argument does not yield a result on your question because at the end of it they introduce a finite extension $k'/k$ of some unknowable degree $m$ and only descend $E_{k'}$ to an elliptic curve $E'_0$ over $k_0$, rather than descend $E$; i.e., $(E'_0)_k$ is merely a $k$-form of $E$ (in my notation, they say nothing about the image on H$^1$'s). Their method exerts no control on the specific field "upstairs" from which they build a descent.